# how can i set atributes to @Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

when iam traying to fill a middle table  for example when a student want to add a coourse i have in my view a DropDownList for the seletec student a  DropDownList for all the course and a DropDownList  for all student

```
table sample
{
id,
studentid,
courseid,
grade,
studentTeacher
}
```

my controller

```
ViewBag.Student= new SelectList(db.Course.Where(c => c.StudentId== id), "StudentId","FullName");
ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Course, "CourseId ", "Name");
ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.Student, "StudentId","FullName");
```

in my view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Student")
 @Html.DropDownList("CourseId ")
 @Html.DropDownList("StudentId ", string.Empty)
```

i get an erro it say There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Student'.

so i guees is looking for a key StudentId, so the question will be how can i tell the DropDownList to look to that key (StudentId) from the (Student)

Answer (score 0):

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Student'.

It means that you haven't provided any `SelectListItem` collection (let's say any data) to the dropdown. ASP.NET MVC automatically tries to find data in the ViewData collection with the same key as property named. In your case it's 'Student' because you have provided such property name to the `@Html.DropDownList("Student")`.

Try to set data to `ViewData["Student"]` collection, or populate it directly:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Student", ViewBag.Student)
// etc.
```